# Spring Updating Version

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to update spring from 3.2 to 4.1.6 version, I downloaded the jars and replace them with the old one.

The question is must I change the schemaLocation versions in the application-context.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an exception and the application works then no.
If you have the schemas without the version:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

instead of

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
```

the framewrok will get the right schema.